# Currency format in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to show the number value as currency. The number value comes from the database through MVC controller to cshtml input object with `ng-model`. I can show the value as currency but according to my scenario i have to change the value and save it using the same input value. How can I do that? Without the currency filter I can change the value and save it. With currency filter I cannot change the input value to save it. The filter prevents me to change the `ng-model` value. I can change the `ng-model` value without currency filter.

Can anyone help me?

The filtered and non-filtered input value picture is in the attachment and the input cshtml code is:

```
<input type="text" id="GiroFeb" autocomplete="off"
       ng-model="moneyvalue | currency:'&#x20BA;'"
       ng-change="notifyChange(money.AccountNumber)" />
```

[image]

Comment: <input type="text" id="GiroFeb" ng-change="notifyChange(money.AccountNumber)" ng-model="moneyvalue | currency:'&#x20BA;'"  autocomplete='off'  />

Comment: Edit your post and add the code there, it helps people understand the question

Comment: Use https://github.com/aguirrel/ng-currency its awesome.